# Is Date between 1st of 1st Month and 29th of 7th month of any year (Sql Server 2008+)

Tags: sql-server

I need to check if a Date is between 1st of 1st month and 29th of 7th month of any year.
Before going ahead and hacking extracting Month Day from the date and comparing it to being between 0101 and 0729 (or just checking if the date dd mm is less than 629) type of hideousity solution, I must ask is there a function to check wether any date falls in between particalr days and month , invariant of the it's year.

Other wise extracting months and days from the date and doing some hacky arithmatic  is easy, but I want to be leave a better code for the poor programmer who will come after me and not having to guess why the hell some freaky made up arithmatic is going on, I rather be explicit even if it takes longer.

Comment: Is your date contained in a single column?  Why not use `BETWEEN` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : Between what and what? It could be any year

Comment: From the [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(v=sql.110).aspx) documentation there does not seem to exist better solution than writing `where MONTH(datecolumn)<7 or ( MONTH(datecolumn)=7 and DAY(datecolumn) <29)` (or30 if you want to include July 29th).

Comment: My suggestion is WHERE MONTH(DATE1)*100+DAY(DATE1) BETWEEN 101 AND 629

Comment: @AbdulRasheed : Thanks, that is what I am trying to avoid! was hoping dont have to do voodoo arithmatic!

Comment: Which is it? July or June? Your title and some of your text talks of July, but then your numeric comparisons seem to be using "6" for the month.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : July, what ever month that is 06, 07 ?I change the post so it does not need know what month is what number, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option:

```
DECLARE @TheDate date = '2016-07-29';

SELECT 1 
WHERE DATEADD(Year, -(YEAR(@TheDate) - 2000), @TheDate) 
    BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2000-07-29'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from TableWithNoName where DateField1 between DATETIMEFROMPARTS( YEAR(DateField1),1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 )  and DATETIMEFROMPARTS( YEAR(DateField1),7, 29, 23, 59, 59, 999 )
```

assuming DateField1 is a Date Value

Comment: This should be a part of the question, not an answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled : why? It is what I ended up using after I got no aswers, so it is actually an answer.

Comment: This wouldn't work in 2008 (luckily) and even if it did, would potentially return false result (even if the BDate is just a date value without a time part).

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12313703)

Comment: @gofr1 : this is a complete answer! i ended up using it !! triple exclamtion mark is next !!!!

Comment: @Arjang not only me mark it to Recommend Deletion. Please, rephrase your answer so it will be clear enough to be an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
where datetimeField < dateFromParts( year( dateTimeField ), 7, 30)
```

EDIT: Above would work in 2012 and later. For 2008 you could do some arithmetic which is "very simple" for a developer:

```
where datetimeField < CAST(CAST(year(dateTimeField) AS CHAR(4))+'0730' AS DATE);
```

Or simplified a bit:

```
where datetimeField < CAST(year(dateTimeField) AS CHAR(4))+'0730';
```

PS: A common pitfall in using BETWEEN (which acts like x >= v1 and x <= v2) on a datetime field, where the field might have time part, is not suggested and would never help to precisely get the correct records (because there is no way to specify the ending time). Instead you should always use x >= v1 and x < v2 style where v2 is the minimum exclusive upper value. ie: To get all the sales in May 2000 (saleDate has time component):

```
saleDate >= '20000501' and saleDate < '20000601'
```

NOT:

```
saleDate between  '20000501' and '20000531'
```

OR NOT:

```
saleDate >= '20000501' and saleDate <= '20000531'
```

Comment: Take my plus 1! But this is exactly what I was trying to avoid, simple for a developer does not mean clean, no vodoo aritmatic and screwing around with strings :)

Comment: It is clean. If your concern is using strings then you could go to a longer route and say: month(dateTimeField) < 7 or (month(dateTimeField) = 7 and day(dateTimeField) < 30)